# changing directory in Terminal

Tags: gradle

I need to change directory in Terminal

This is the path which I need: % cd /Users/cuninkapavol/IdeaProjects/Simple Chatty Bot (Java)

After enter I have this statement: zsh: unknown file attribute: J

where is a problem if path is right

project is build with Gradle

I need to get to the file  Simply Chatty Boot (Java) in Terminal  and then I want push project to GitHub

any help will be great, Thank you.

Comment: Rename your folder to `Simple Chatty Bot` without (Java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put quotes around the whole file name:

cd "/Users/cuninkapavol/IdeaProjects/Simple Chatty Bot (Java)"

Without the quotes, zsh is interpreting (Java) as what it calls a glob qualifier and that leads to an error.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which terminal you are using the solution to your answer may vary. You need to explicitly paste what command you are running and which terminal you are commanding. It is likely your path is incorrect due to the syntax; You have spaces and symbols in the path you provided, thus you likely need to wrap your path in quotations to let the shell know that you are passing it a contiguous string... Another possibility is that you are failing to set an appropriate reference to start your path and thus are pointing to the wrong place in your file system. When you reference "/", this codes for "root". Usually the location of this root is obvious, but when using multiple hard drives the root can obviously only be on one drive. If the folder you wish to change to is on your secondary hard drive, you must specify the drive identifier as the start of your path e.g "D:/".

It is standard for a terminal to contain a command in PATH which prints the string of the working directory a shell is in, which you can look up and run appropriately.

In truth this is a verbose answer for what should be easily trouble-shootable via a search engine. Hopefully it can shed some light on some fundamental holes you have in your understanding of a shell and interacting with it.

Comment: The OP may not understand this, but the question is about the shell and not the terminal.

Comment: @Nibowaka Go ahead and mark the question as solved if the answer was appropriate.